# How to break a .txt file into array? (It's supposed to work but doesn't)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert each line in a .txt file into an element of an array

**ERROR: It just put everything in 1 cell:**

```
[ 'Game1 | 111111\rGame2 | 22222\rGame3 | 333333\rGame4 | 444\rGame5 | 555555555\rGame6 | 6666666666' ]
```

I tried reading the file, then using split (it worked, but now it only puts everything in 1 array cell)

```
fs.readFile("./SETTINGS/txt.txt", "utf8", (error, data) => {
  if(error) {
    callback("Error loading database",{});
  } else {
    let keys = data.split("\n");
});
```

Expecting to break the txt file into an array (a line in each cell)

Comment: Have you checked the real code of the txt file, maybe the breakline character is not  a `\n` but something else

Comment: https://gyazo.com/60c71debc8742a67864203265a229392
I looked around at other places, and it seems I'm doing this right

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your string is separated by "\r". Try splitting on that or maybe "\r\n". You can also build fancier regexes that will recognise multiple newline variants.

Comment: It surprisingly worked (even though \n worked for me before then abruplty stopped)

thx ;)

Comment: Hmmm, okay then. Still might be worth using a split regex that wont break under Windows/Linux/Mac

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `split()` is being executed before file is read. Use `fs.readFileSync()` instead

> **Synchronous** — is one step after the other. Until the first step is completed the second step will not even be looked at. Very simple, but it does hang the io on that one task which must be completed. All else is suspended.
>
> **Asynchronous** — moves with the inertia of the first throw by the quarterback. The code is processed, but along the way you may want to cause it to wait or check for the completion of a task.
>
> *taken from [Node.js — Sync? Async? Speak English, Please!](https://medium.com/@tedwgross/sync-async-speak-english-please-6f21d47134c) by Ted Gross*

Full code:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// create normalized path for windows and os 
const filepath = path.join('SETTINGS','txt.txt')

const file = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8')
const lines = file.split('\n')

console.log(lines)
```

[View in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-l43f4?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&moduleview=1&view=editor)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the special escaped characters, they're `\r` not `\n`. Split on those instead:

```
let keys = data.split("\r");
```

Or use a regex to split on both of them, no matter which one comes into play. You can also add other characters to this later with very little effort.

```
let keys = data.split(/\r|\n/);
```